# Why when upload files/images using axios, multer, cloudinary. get Error: EROFS: read-only file system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, mern

In this MERN app. localhost perfect work. But this is hosted to cyclic then error this. When i upload images in api using axios with formdata. The response gets

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/src/public/images/images-168.jpg
```

And this is my multer configuration

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "../public/images"));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniquesuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniquesuffix + ".jpeg");
  },
});

const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Unsupported file format", false);
    // cb(new Error("Wrong extension type"), false);
  }
};

exports.uploadPhoto = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: multerFilter,
  limits: { fileSize: 2000000 },
});
```

finally images i upload to cloudinary.

I want to get response status 200 and category create success.

Answer (score 0):

Multer destination must be in `/tmp` dir, it's the only location guaranteed to work. It's a normal issue...
Cyclic file system docs are [here](https://docs.cyclic.sh/concepts/file_system) ; you can read:

> "Files created by the fs module are read-only once the project is
> deployed to Cyclic.sh. This results in an EROFS: Error Read-Only File
> System error."